# Get all elements of a specific type using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, checkbox, css-selectors

Hello I have been using JQuery for quite a while. I need to get the ids of the checked elements. I have all my checkboxes as rows sitting inside a container, and I want to get the ids of all the checkboxes that have are checked.

I would use

```
$("#container input:checkbox")
```

to get all the checkboxes in that container, and then would check for which ones have been checked.

To do the same in ExtJS, i have been using the "get" method, and would do a

```
Ext.get('input')
```

which gives me all the input items, but I still have to check if they are of type "checkbox", is there a way I could get only the checkbox elements from DOM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent function to JQuery's selector would be either `Ext.query`, or `Ext.DomQuery.selectNode`.

`Ext.Query` works in a very similar way as JQuery ([see how the selectors work here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.DomQuery)).

In your case, you could try this:

```
Ext.query("#container input:checked")
```

Of course, this will only obtain DOM values rather than Ext components.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, but when I run the command Ext.query("#container input:checkbox"); , I get an error? I want to retrieve all the checkboxes first, I have radio buttons too in that container!!

Comment: It would be Ext.query("#container input[type='checkbox']"). Thank you Nicholas!!

Comment: Apologies for the lack of specificity. I usually work with Ext components, but I'm glad I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CheckboxGroup object, you can use the getValues() method which will return an Array of the Checkboxes which you can use to look at the values...